# Sortable tables in MediaWiki 1.23.6+

Tags: mediawiki

The more recent versions of MediaWiki no longer include skins/common/shared.css. By copying bits from the old shared.css into my custom skin, I can regain things like the float property.

I can find the old wikitable code, but I can't seem to make tables sortable in my custom skin.  The sortable table code works fine when viewed with the Vector skin.

This leads me to believe I ought to be able to find how the sorting works somewhere in the Vector skin files, but I haven't had any luck so far. Does anyone know where I can find the code that will allow me to use sortable tables in my custom skin?

Edited to add: I have found jquery.ui.sortable.js in resources/lib/jquery.ui, but I have no idea what to put into my custom skin's code to refer to that and make table sorting work.

Answer (score 0):

In recent releases of MediaWiki, you just have to use the ["wikitable" class](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#class.3D.22wikitable.22) together with the ["sortable" class](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Sorting#Sorting_rows_of_a_table).

Example from the manual:

```
 {| class="wikitable sortable"
 |-
 ! Fruit   !! Price
 |-
 | Apples  || £0.95
 |-
 | Oranges || £0.85
 |-
 | Pears   || £1.15
 |}
```